# Ring advancements: can Void Ring be your lowest ring?

Tags: l5r, l5r-5e

On p. 97 of the Legends of the Five Rings 5th edition rulebook it says:

> Cannot increase a ring to a value greater than lowest ring + Void Ring. Maximum 5.

Does this mean that if your Void Ring is 1, the maximum you can increase any other ring to is 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes but...

You start with Void 1 at the start of character creation, so if you happen to end Character Creation with Void 1, you can not increase any other ring to more than 2 with experience in the game. To eliminate that limiting factor, you need to raise your void ring to 2 for 6 XP, raising your lock to 3 (if some other ring remains at 1) or 4.

**However** you can end character creation with a ring of 3 or more from character creation as character creation is not done bound by the XP advancement.